# How to make local USB port to work with Azure virtual machine

Tags: android, azure, windows-phone-8, usb, nxt

I am new to Azure, I want to connect my local USB port to `Azure VM` (for debugging apps), how can I do this?

If I can connect local USB (USB of my PC) to `Azure VM`, I can make 100% use of Azure as PC, and I can run apps without any problem.
Please help out doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply right click on the rdp file and click on edit and select local resource there you can find option called ports

Comment: do you know what are the key: value to be added? ( if needs to be done from unix OS → txt editor)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answer above - you can also configure under Drives the option so that all new USBs you plug in will show up on your VM.

[image]

Comment: How do you show iPhone and Android devices as well?