# How to connect Android device to Azure VM with Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, azure

I want to connect my Android device to Azure VM with Visual Studio so I can debug and deploy an app. I created a VM by using a template that includes VS. On the RDP file, I edited settings so that all ports are redirected to the VM. This works fine with hard drives, but I can't get my Android device to show on the VM. Consequently, VS isn't aware of the device. USB debugging on the device and developer mode on the Win10 VM are enabled.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29611391/812582

I checked all boxes on the above screenshot.

Are there any tricks I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, based on my understanding, it sounds like you want to map the Android device host USB to the remote Win10 VM over network for implementing remote debug.

There are some device driver software which can help you access remote USB device via `USB over network`. Meanwhile, I searched an existing SO thread [Using remote host's USB port as local USB (Linux and Win)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837277/using-remote-hosts-usb-port-as-local-usb-linux-and-win) is very similar with your needs, but the [`USB/IP`](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) project be mentioned in the thread seems to be not suitable for your scenario which is between two Windows OS.

Suggest that try to use some business software like [`USB over network`](http://www.usb-over-network.com/) if you will.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I'll take a look at that software, but I think MS should provide some kind of support for this. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Mark13426, Thanks for your feedback.